# innerRef to third party component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, styled-components

I'm using Redux Form together with Styled Components.

I would like to get the ref of a Redux Form Field, so I can focus it in certain conditions.

The code looks something like: (a little bit simplified)

```
export const SomeForm = () => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
    <FormLabel htmlFor="comment">Comment:</FormLabel>
    <CommentTextArea
      name="comment"
      component="textArea"
      maxLength="250"
      innerRef={commentBox => this.commentBox = commentBox}
    />
  </form>
);
```

Where the `CommentTextArea` is a styled component like such:

```
const CommentTextArea = styled(Field)`
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: black;
  height: 6.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
`;
```

The problem is that the `innerRef`'s `this` value is undefined.  Is there a way to get access to the ref of the `textArea` and focus it when necessary?

(`FormLabel` is also a styled component, but not necessary to show it for the problem)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! I wrote `redux-form` and I adore `styled-components`, but it never occurred to me to do `styled(Field)`. That's pretty wild, as I don't consider `Field` to be a "rendering component" that can be "styled".

However, I think the puzzle piece you are missing is that you need to pass [a `withRef` prop](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/Field.md/#-code-withref-boolean-code-optional-) to `Field`, which will then enable you to use `getRenderedComponent()` to get the actual `textarea` component. Something like:

```
<CommentTextArea
  name="comment"
  component="textArea"
  maxLength="250"
  withRef
  innerRef={commentBox => this.commentBox = commentBox.getRenderedComponent()}
/>
```

I'm just conjecturing here. I've never attempted this pattern myself.